# How to listen to onmessage event of websocket from a different file?

Tags: javascript, websocket, phaser-framework

I'm creating a multiplayer game using Phaser 3. I have created a Socket.js file in which I'm creating a websocket instance and defining functions to listen to websocket events.

```
let websocket;
const url = "wss://abc/dev";

export const socketInit = () => {
    websocket = new WebSocket(url);
    websocket.onopen = (evt) => {
        onOpen(evt);
    };
    websocket.onclose = (evt) => {
        onClose(evt);
    };
    websocket.onmessage = (evt) => {
        onMessage(evt);
    };
    websocket.onerror = (evt) => {
        onError(evt);
    };
};

export const sendMessage = (message) => {
    console.log("SENT: " + JSON.stringify(message));
    websocket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
};

const onOpen = (evt) => {
    if (websocket.readyState === 1) {
        console.log("WEBSOCKET CONNECTED"); 
        }

};

const onClose = (evt) => {
    console.log("CLOSE", evt);
};

const onMessage = (evt) => {
    console.log(evt.data);
};

const onError = (evt) => {
    console.log("Error", evt);
    websocket.close();
};
```

I have another file called `mainScene.js` where I want to get the data the `onMessage` function receives. I'm not able to figure out how to get the data to this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want to pass the data. If you simply want to pass data to the current scene. *(and there is only one scene, or atleast the scene is always the active/current one)*

You could simply call a function *(like for example `passData`)* on the scene, like so:

```
// I assume the mainScene.js could look something like this
class MainScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    ...
    passData(data){
        // ... do something with the data
    }
}


// from the file containing the socket script ...
// ... and if the game variable of the Phaser.Game is defined globaly.
const onMessage = (evt) => {
     game.scene.keys.MainScene.passData(evt.data);
};
```

> **btw.:** there are some good examples, how to create a multiplayer game with phaser [like this one](https://phasertutorials.com/creating-a-simple-multiplayer-game-in-phaser-3-with-an-authoritative-server-part-1/), it is abit dated but should cover the basics.